# WOW JS Not work with One page scroll

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, wow.js

i use this plugin:
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html

Every time you change the slide, I would like to do to all elements of each section of one animations with this plugin:
https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

Other times I used WOW JS and it works great but this combo WOW JS + ONEPAGE SCROLL not work..

Only the first element work, other slide not show correctly.

Someone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Burimi, onepage scroll doesn't actually scroll the site but instead uses the property `translate3d` in the plugin's container.

I would encourage you to use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead, which solves this issue by adding the option `scrollBar:true` as you can see in [this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html), providing as well a better user experience keeping the scroll bar.

As explained in [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions#parallax-doesnt-work-with-fullpagejs):

> Parallax, **as well as many other plugins which depends on the scrolling of the site**, listens the scrollTop property of javascript. fullPage.js doesn't actually scroll the site but it changes the top or translate3d property of the site. Only when using the fullPage.js option scrollBar:true or autoScrolling:false it will actually scroll the site in a way it is accessible for the scrollTop property.

If you don't want to use the `scrollBar` option, you can still use callbacks such as `afterLoad` or `onLeave` as detailed [in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks).

Additionally, fullPage.js provides compatibility with old browsers such as IE>7, Opera 12... and it provides more options which can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is because OnePage Scroll plugin does not trigger a normal browser scroll, so you have to use `afterMove`event of OnePage Scroll to trigger WOW Animations.

```
$(".main").onepage_scroll({
    afterMove : function(index){
        var this_slide = $(".main").eq(index);
        //you can perform a manual animation of this_slide, so check out the WOW Documentation
    }
});
```